# HELP - impdp from expdp - do i need to get the .dmp file to the RDS DATA_PUMP_DIR

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, amazon-rds, impdp

I've been beating my head against a stubborn wall trying to get a expdp of an oracle schema (on premises db) loaded to my new Oracle RDS instance. 
I saw this comment from you and it sounds exactly like what I want to do. Do you remember how you 'pulled the files from S3, tweaked them, then loaded them into RDS' ?

"For what it's worth... in the end we needed to process the files a bit. So I simply pulled the files from S3, tweaked them, then loaded them into RDS. The retrieval is fast enough that the potential gains of FuseOverAmazon or a pipe are really quite small for us. – mdahlman Dec 4 '13 at 23:34 "

I would love to solve this issue without getting an rman backup of the oracle db.

Jennifer

:)

Answer (score 0):

I really don´t know how this S3 method for importing a database to RDS works, I really want to hear about it. In all the papers I read about migrating an Oracle database to RDS there is always an EC2 instance with the database in the middle.

As I see the process is to export by datapump, and then move via a database link this export to RDS and then ingest this dump to the RDS.

I´m talking about this guides:
https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/strategies-for-migrating-oracle-database-to-aws.pdf
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html

Comment: Well I got the dump file to S3 (expdp file) and then copied that file down to Ec2. From here i used a perl script to get the dump file up to the RDS back end DATA_PUMP_DIR.  Now I'm stuck as I can't seem to get the file to import. Ive tried impdp and i tried using a SQL script with dbms_datapump commands.

Comment: I went around the DBLINK because I can't access my source db and target dbs at the same time.

Comment: Why you´re putting your dump on S3? why not using the EC2 storage? Im which of this steps you got stuck? Step 1: Grant privileges to user on source database
Step 2: Use DBMS_DATAPUMP to create a dump file
Step 3: Create a database link to the target DB instance
Step 4: Use DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER to copy the exported dump file to the Amazon RDS instance
Step 5: Import the dump file into a database on the Amazon RDS instance
Step 6: Clean up